# JAXB: problems with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-rs

We want to implement a RESTful-Webservice with JAX-RS and JAXB. We have a PUT method that consumes xml, that looks like the following:

```
<mailAccount>
    <id>-1</id>
    <name>test</name>
    <mailaddress>test@gmx.de</mailaddress>
    <password>1234</password>
    <servertype>IMAP</servertype>
    <host>hallo</host>
    <port>5678</port>
    <encryption>SSL/TLS</encryption>
    <authentication>true</authentication>
    <interval>12</interval>
</mailAccount>
```

We also have a MailAccount.class that is mapped to the xml.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MailAccount {

private String name;
private String mailaddress;
private String password;
private String servertype;
private String host;
private int port;
private String encryption;
private boolean authentication;
private int interval;
private int id;

getter + setter...
}
```

The PUT-Method looks like the following:

```
@PUT()
@Path("/addMailAccount")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response addMailAccount(JAXBElement<MailAccount> mail) throws Exception{
    MailAccount mailAccounts = mail.getValue();

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MailAccount.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(mailAccounts, sw);

    String xmlConsume = sw.toString();

    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlConsume));

    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(MailAccountService.class.getResource("/emailAddresses.xsd"));

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    //validator.validate(source);

    return Response.status(200).entity(xmlConsume +"..."+ mailAccounts.getMailadress()).build();
}
```

Our goal is to marshalling the JAXB-Element to validate it against an XML-Schema. But the problem is the marshalling: First of all the elements are not in the correct order. The use of the propOrder Tag results every time in an internal server error.

The second problem is that the element "mailaddress" is empty. It is not marshalling and when i put it into the Response of this method, the value is null.

Here is what the PUT-Method is returning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mailAccount>
    <authentication>true</authentication>
    <encryption>SSL/TLS</encryption>
    <host>hallo</host>
    <id>-1</id>
    <interval>12</interval>
    <name>test</name>
    <password>1234</password>
    <port>5678</port>
    <servertype>IMAP</servertype>
</mailAccount>
...null
```

Comment: Can you not alphabetically sort the tags in the XML you are feeding it? That will solve the order problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple items that should help:

**propOrder**

Below is an example of applying a `propOrder` to your class.  It is important to remember that you need to include all mapped fields/properties that are mapped to XML elements in the `propOrder`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "name", "mailaddress", "password", "servertype", "host", "port", "encryption", "authentication", "interval"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MailAccount {

    private String name;
    private String mailaddress;
    private String password;
    private String servertype;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String encryption;
    private boolean authentication;
    private int interval;
    private int id;

}
```

**Doing Schema Validation as Part of the Marshal Operation**

Below is a standalone example that demonstrates how you can leverage schema validation as part of the marshal operation instead of doing it as a separate operation (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MailAccount.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum20699078/input.xml");
        MailAccount mailAccount = (MailAccount) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(MailAccountService.class.getResource("/emailAddresses.xsd"));
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);

        marshaller.marshal(mailAccount, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved both problems, the order of the elements and now the element emailaddress is evaluated correctly!. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For all those, who have to implement the XML validation with JAX-RS webservice, this is my PUT-Method after the hints from above. It works now fine for me.

```
@PUT()
@Path("/addMailAccount")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response addMailAccount(JAXBElement<MailAccount> mail) throws MailAccountServiceException{
    String xmlConsume = "";

    try{
        MailAccount mailAccounts = mail.getValue();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MailAccount.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(MailAccountService.class.getResource("/mailAccount.xsd"));
        jaxbMarshaller.setSchema(schema);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(mailAccounts, sw);

        xmlConsume = sw.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new MailAccountServiceException("Fehlerhafte Anfrage: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity(xmlConsume).build();
}
```

Comment: This is years too late, but don't make a new JAXBContext instance for every call. Creating a new one every time is a lot of overhead that can be the cause of big performance issues.